# Count unique values using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have data of the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'param': ['a', 'a', 'b', np.nan, 'a', 'a', np.nan]
})
print(df)

#    group param
# 0      1     a
# 1      1     a
# 2      2     b
# 3      3   NaN
# 4      3     a
# 5      3     a
# 6      4   NaN
```

Non-null values within groups are always the same. I want to count the non-null value for each group (where it exists) once, and then find the total counts for each value.

I'm currently doing this in the following (clunky and inefficient) way:

```
param = []
for _, group in df[df.param.notnull()].groupby('group'):
    param.append(group.param.unique()[0])
print(pd.DataFrame({'param': param}).param.value_counts())

# a    2
# b    1
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this more cleanly and without using a loop, but I just can't seem to work it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

I think you can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
print (df.groupby('param')['group'].nunique())
param
a    2
b    1
Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html), then create new `df` by [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html), reshape to `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
a = df[df.param.notnull()].groupby('group')['param'].unique()
print (pd.DataFrame.from_records(a.values.tolist()).stack().value_counts())
a    2
b    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I test it with `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'param': ['a', 'c', 'b', np.nan, 'c', 'a', np.nan]
})`, but your code return different output because use only first unique element of list in each `group`. My code return all unique values. Please check it if I understand what do you need. Thank you.

Comment: How we get the column names

Comment: @dondapati - add `.reset_index()`

Comment: Note that this solution only produce a series, not a dataframe. Using @datapug solution creates a dataframe.

Answer (score 87):

This is just an add-on to the solution in case you want to compute not only unique values but other aggregate functions:

```
df.groupby(['group']).agg(['min', 'max', 'count', 'nunique'])
```

Comment: This solution will create a dataframe.

Answer (score 21):

The above answers work too, but in case you want to add a column with unique_counts to your existing data frame, you can do that using [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

```
df['distinct_count'] = df.groupby(['param'])['group'].transform('nunique')
```

output:

```
   group param  distinct_count
0      1     a             2.0
1      1     a             2.0
2      2     b             1.0
3      3   NaN             NaN
4      3     a             2.0
5      3     a             2.0
6      4   NaN             NaN
```

and to check the group counts as highted by @jezrael.

```
print (df.groupby('param')['group'].nunique())
```

```
param
a    2
b    1
Name: group, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 9):

I know it has been a while since this was posted, but I think this will help too.
I wanted to count unique values and filter the groups by number of these unique values, this is how I did it:

```
df.groupby('group').agg(['min','max','count','nunique']).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This way is faster and is more convenient:

```
df.groupby('param').agg({'group':lambda x: len(pd.unique(x))})
```

Comment: Faster than what? Can you show us the code and data that you are using to compare the timings between alternative methods?