# pandas: find invalid records where for a given value in one column, another column contains multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my DataFrame, for a given value in the `id` column, the value in `doc_no` column must be a single value. In the below example, the records with `id-1` are invalid, because they have more than one value for the `doc_no` column.

```
import pandas as pd

def find_non_unique_values():
    print()
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': ['id-1', 'id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'], 
        'doc_no': ['doc-1', 'doc-2', 'doc-3', 'doc-4']
    })
    
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    # default display width is 80
    pd.set_option("display.width", 150)
    
    print("dataframe info:")
    df.info()
    print()
    
    print(df.head(4))
    
find_non_unique_values()
```

How can I find all such invalid records?

Note: I do not want to drop the duplicates. I want to identify the invalid records and notify the user for correction.

Comment: there are many questions about this already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415017/count-unique-values-using-pandas-groupby

Comment: Looks like you want `df.drop_duplicates('id', keep=False)`

Comment: I do not want to drop duplicates

Comment: @AllSolutions if you want to keep the duplicates `df[df.duplicated(subset='id', keep=False)]`, doing the same as the accepted answer but much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `filter`:

```py
import pandas as pd

def find_non_unique_values():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': ['id-1', 'id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'], 
        'doc_no': ['doc-1', 'doc-2', 'doc-3', 'doc-4']
    })

    # Group by 'id', then filter out groups where the count of unique 'doc_no' values is greater than 1
    invalid_records = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x['doc_no'].unique()) > 1)

    print("Invalid records:")
    print(invalid_records)

find_non_unique_values()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415017/count-unique-values-using-pandas-groupby

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the `id` column and aggregate using [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) that finds the count of unique items in the group. Than just filter where the count is greater than 1:

```py
df.groupby("id")["doc_no"].nunique().loc[lambda x: x < 2].index
```

Comment: Looks like a complicated way of doing `df.loc[df['id'].duplicated(keep=False), 'doc_no']`